# JSON Data output

Tags: json, perl

Below is the Perl code having JSON data:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $var = '{

    "episode1": {
      "title":"Cartman Gets an Anal Probe",
      "id":"103511",
      "airdate":"08.13.97",
      "episodenumber":"101",
      "available":"true",
      "when":"08.13.97"
    }
  },
  {
    "episode2": {
      "title":"Weight Gain 4000",
      "id":"103516",
      "airdate":"08.20.97",
      "episodenumber":"102",
      "available":"true",
      "when":"08.20.97"
    }
}';

my $resp = JSON::jsonToObj( $var );

print Dumper ($resp);
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'episode1' => {
    'when' => '08.13.97',
    'episodenumber' => '101',
    'airdate' => '08.13.97',
    'title' => 'Cartman Gets an Anal Probe',
    'id' => '103511',
    'available' => 'true'
  }
};
```

I am dumping a JSON data but only `episode1` is dumped in the output. But, I want both `episode1` and `episode2` to be displayed when I dump. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write valid JSON.

From [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
Parse error on line 14:
...: "08.13.97"    }},{    "episode2": 
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF'
```

If you want an array of objects, you need an array in the data: `[...]`.

Comment: @user2201935 — The reduction in content makes the code a better example of a reduced test case. The loss of indenting makes it worse. The problem you actually have is still the same, and this answer still explains what you need to do to fix it.